# how to convert the string received in php to json array and loop through it?

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

I am sending a json array converted to String using StringEntity class from android. I receive a string like the one below in php.

```
   {
    "introduceesJson": [
        {
            "infoName": "Aa",
            "direction": "2",
            "version": "1",
            "infoNumber": "96 35 874125"
        },
        [
            {
                "infoName": "Aa",
                "direction": "2",
                "version": "1",
                "infoNumber": "96 35 874125"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Now, i want to convert this into json array and loop through it. guys, please help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: deode it using json_decode and save it in an array

Comment: @habibulhaq, code please. please.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray("Your_String");
            for (int i=0;i<arr.length();i++) {
                JSONObject object = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                String data = object.getString("Your_key");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: not java. how to loop in php?. Anyways, thanks a lot for the response

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
 $a='  {
        "introduceesJson": [
            {
                "infoName": "Aa",
                "direction": "2",
                "version": "1",
                "infoNumber": "96 35 874125"
            },
            [
                {
                    "infoName": "Aa",
                    "direction": "2",
                    "version": "1",
                    "infoNumber": "96 35 874125"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }';

    $res=json_decode($a,true);
    $data=array();
    $data=$res['introduceesJson'];
    echo sizeof($data);
```